# <h2> not centering with margin auto because it is full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I use class="m-x-auto" on my `<h2>` tags which effectively sets margin-left and margin-right to auto.

It is working for me for most of my `<h2>` tags but not for this one.

It is because in this example my `<h2>` seems to have full width (100%) and that means there is not space for a margin.

Photo of what it should be:

[image]

Photo of what it is:

[image]

How do I stop me `<h2>` from being full width so that it centers?

Comment: if it takes up the entire screen why not use text-align:center?

Comment: @NilesTanner That works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: auto` just center the `h2`.
The issue here is the `width: 100%` by default because the tag `h2` is `display: block` element.

So one solution is that you can set `text-align: center`.